# Magento add tier price programmatically but with custom fields

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have a problem about add product tier price by code. I did some research that there is a magento API that could be used to add tier price. However, since I have customized our magento and add a new field to the tier price, which is "production time", I don't know how to add tier price via API anymore.

Here is the sample code

```
$proxy = new SoapClient(Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('API user','API Key');
$tierPrices[] = array(
    'website'           => 'all',
    'customer_group_id' => 'all',
    'production_time    => $data[2],
    'qty'               => $data[3],
    'price'             => $data[4]
);
 try {
        $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_tier_price.update', array($sku, $tierPrices));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

I will get an error says "invalid tier price".

Any idea why does it happen? or is there other ways to add tier prices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that it's easiest to load the model that the API uses for Tiered Prices so that it can help you by validating your data for you.

```
$tierPrices = array();

$tierPrices[] = array(
    'customer_group_id' => 1,       // or 'all' or whatever your customer group ID is
    'qty'               => 1,       // Must be greater than 0
    'price'             => 5.99,    // Use an int here, don't currency format
    'website_id'        => 0        // or whatever website ID you need to set this to
);

// Set more tiered prices here if you'd like...

$tierPriceModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_tierprice_api');

// Assume 12345 is your product ID
$tierPriceModel->update(12345, $tierPrices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fo whose like me who were wondering why tier prices were not updated taking into account website_id this is because there is a mistake in @Tyler V. code, or api code has changed.

This is the correct way to format new tier prices :

```
$tierPrices[] = array(
    'customer_group_id' => 'all',     
    'qty'               => 1,       
    'price'             => 5.99,    
    'website'        => 0         
);
```

This is no longer **website_id** but **website** when you specify website into tier price array!

Answer (score -1):

Better than API where are not all the functions you can use standard Magento script, you only need to be placed anywhere in magento folder:

```
require("../../app/Mage.php");
Mage::init();

// Set an Admin Session
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(1);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setUser($userModel);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());


foreach ($youritemlist as $item) {  


   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item);  

    if(is_object($product)) {              


                $product->setTierPrice($yourprice);  
                echo "..(set)..";


                      $product->save();                          

                       echo "..saved\n";                                      

      }; // end testing of product exist              


}; // enf foreach
```

Comment: It would be more helpful it you showed how to set $yourprice correctly.